# Edge Loops "get broken"

Tags: modeling, edges

I am learning blender and can't understand why edge loops "get broken" (May be a specific name for it).

Taking the picture below as example:[image: Example]

When I try to create an edge loops it stops on the top of the front face (marked edges).

I don't understand what make edge loops not being possible to be continued. I mean I expect the edgle loop to go all the way like the line I draw in red.

I could understand if there are n-gons or double vertices, but what's wrong in the mes below?

Just for info, the left object is just the "preview" of an array modifier used on the right object.